# Multiple pages with different in QGIS print composer / layouts?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

Is it possible to make **multiple pages with different size** in qgis print composer?. so that when i want to print different maps in qgis i will just do it in one print composer.

Comment: which QGIS version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible in QGIS 3.0

After you add pages, R-click on the page to edit its properties.
Select page size that you want.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note, this function may change to a different menu in 3.2

Comment: It still works in QGIS 3.16